# Compare an array of objects and an array of singular values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two arrays. One is filled with objects, the other is filled with values. See code below:

```
const data = [
   {id: 1, name: 'ben'},
   {id: 2, name: 'ben'}, 
   {id: 3, name: 'ben'}, 
   {id: 4, name: 'ben'}
];
const ids = [1,3,4,5]
```

I want to select only objects from the data array where the `id` property matches any of the value in the ids array.

How best should I go about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that might help.

```js
const data = [{id:1, name:'ben'},{id:2, name:'ben'}, {id:3, name:'ben'}, {id:4, name:'ben'}];
const ids = [1,3,4,5];

const newData = data.filter(chunk => ids.includes(chunk.id));
console.log("Filtered Data", newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest approach to do this is array `filter` function:

```js
const data = [{id:1, name:'ben'},{id:2, name:'ben'}, {id:3, name:'ben'}, {id:4, name:'ben'}];
const ids = [1, 3, 4, 5];

const result = data.filter(({id}) => ids.includes(id));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way, you can use `some` method placed inside `filter` method:

```
data.filter(chunk => ids.some(s => s == chunk.id));
```

An example:

```js
const data = [{id:1, name:'ben'},{id:2, name:'ben'}, {id:3, name:'ben'}, {id:4, name:'ben'}];
const ids = [1,3,4,5];

const newData = data.filter(chunk => ids.some(s => s== chunk.id));
console.log("Filtered Data", newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the initial array and [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to exclude unmatching entities:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "ben" },
  { id: 2, name: "ben" },
  { id: 3, name: "ben" },
  { id: 4, name: "ben" }
];
const ids = [1, 3, 4, 5];

const filteredData = data.filter(dataItem => ids.includes(dataItem.id));
console.log(filteredData); // [{"id":1,"name":"ben"},{"id":3,"name":"ben"},{"id":4,"name":"ben"}]
```